# Get config value in component

Tags: orbeon, xforms

I want to build several autocomplete components that query an external service that the users of my app can easily use. For this purpose, I want to define the relative service path in the component and I'd like the absolute external service URL to be configurable.

I'd like to create a custom config value in `properties-local-prod.xml`, something like `<property as="xs:string" name="oxf.custom.service-ur">http://localhost</property>` and then use it in the resource field of the autocomplete, something like:

```
<fr:autocomplete
    ref="county"
    labelref="@label"
    resource="{$config('oxf.fr.custom.service-url')}/counties?search={$fr-search-value}"
    max-results-displayed="4">
```

Is such a thing possible in Orbeon?

Answer (score 2):

I think that the [`xxf:property()` function](https://doc.orbeon.com/xforms/xpath/extension-functions/extension-core#xxf-property) does exactly what you're looking for.